# Why can't I access the members of a element in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, iterator, function-definition

```
void remove_attack(std::string name) {
    if (!attacks.empty()) {
        for (auto it = attacks.begin(); it != attacks.end(); ++it) {
            if (*it.name == name) {
                attacks.erase(it);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function is trying to remove an attack from a vector named attacks that hold attack structures.

```
struct attack { 
    std::string name = "None";
    unsigned int damage = 0;
    std::string desc = "None";
};
```

The vector looks like:
`std::vector<attack> attacks;`

When I try to compile:

```
main.cpp:52:41: error: ‘class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<attack*, std::vector<attack> >’ has no member named ‘name’
   52 |                                 if (*it.name == name) {
      |
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `*it.name` ≠ `(*it).name`.  Try `it->name` instead.  Or `auto& atk = *it; if (atk.name == name) ...`

Comment: Thanks @Elijay! I forgot about that.

Comment: You are trying to erase from a vector you are iterating over, which doesn't work like that. In any case, please extract a [mcve] next time before asking, it helps focusing on the problem.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but the code doesn’t need to test `if (!attacks.empty())`. If `attacks` is empty it’s `begin()` and `end()` iterators are equal, and the loop will execute 0 times.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write

```
if ( ( *it ).name == name) {
```

or

```
if ( it->name == name) {
```

As for the function then it should be declared and defined the following way

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

void remove_attack( const std::string &name ) 
{
    auto it = std::find_if( std::begin( attacks ), std::end( attacks ),
                            [&]( const auto &a )
                            {
                                return a.name == name;
                            } );    

    if ( it != std::end( attacks ) ) attacks.erase( it );
}
```

Comment: Or `it->name` which also looks cleaner.